# Which is correct "I work nights" or "I work at night"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-request, american-english

I have learned that the correct form is "I work at night". Recently, I saw a movie and one of the characters mentioned "I work nights", Is there any difference between them? Or which one is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on context, they could have practically the same meaning. Any difference is a nuanced one which may be irrelevant in a given context.

> I work nights.

My shift is the night shift, or my normal work-day begins in the evening.

> I work at night.

It is night-time when I work.

The word **nights** implies a regular, routine, or habitual situation.  The phrase **at night** could be understood to mean the same, but it does not entail that meaning. The listener would have to infer it from context.

So, if a cat-burglar said

> I work at night.

It would be a statement of fact.

But if a cat-burglar said

> I work nights.

it could be somewhat humorous, because the cat-burglar is implying that he works the night-shift, that is, that he has a regular routine and a regular job.

Comment: We can also say we work days, mornings, afternoons, or weekends. Oh and there’s “open to close”, but that’s a tangent.

Comment: ColleenV parted ways, Sorry, what do “_open to close_” and "_that’s a tangent_" mean? Thanks!